# Creating Credentials in Azure Data Factory using PowerShell or RestApi

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

There is the article about adding credentials in Azure Data Factory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/credentials?tabs=data-factory

> Associate the user-assigned managed identity to the data factory instance using Azure portal, SDK, PowerShell, REST API.

I am interested in PowerShell or REST API option, the process need to be automated.

I have found New-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedServiceEncryptedCredential in documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/new-azdatafactoryv2linkedserviceencryptedcredential?view=azps-8.1.0 but it doesn't like what I am looking for.

Does anyone have an example of PowerShell code or REST API endpoints to add credential to Azure Data Factory?

Edit:
I am reffering to this credentials:
[image]

Comment: Current status: Microsoft support confirmed that there is no documentation, we are scheduling a call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see anything yet supported for terraform or for the az cli, however there is a REST API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/credential-operations

you can then use this with the az cli rest call e.g.

```
$data_factory_name="my-data-factory"
$resource_group_name="my-resource-group"
$subscription_id=$(az account show --query "id")
$mi_name="my-user-managed-identity"
$credential_name="$mi_name"

$mi_id=$(az identity show --name $mi_name --subscription $subscription_id --resource-group $resource_group_name --query "id" -o tsv)

$url="https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscription_id/resourceGroups/$resource_group_name/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/$data_factory_name/credentials/$credential_name`?api-version=2018-06-01"

$body=[PSCustomObject]@{
  properties = @{
    "type" = "ManagedIdentity"
    "typeProperties" = @{
      "resourceId" = $mi_id
    }
  }
}
$bodyJson = $body | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100
$bodyJson = $bodyJson -replace "`"", "\`""

az rest --method put --url $url --body $bodyJson
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below reference it has detail explanation about:

Creating credentials in azure data factory using Power shell and REST API.

**Reference:**

[Azure Data Factory Using PowerShell by Dhilasu reddy](https://cloudwizardinc.com/2020/03/02/deploy-azure-data-factory-using-powershell/)

[Managed identity for Azure Data Factory and Azure Synapse | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity?tabs=data-factory)

Comment: Unfortunately those links didn't help. I have edited original post. I have added screenshot to what credentials I am referring to.